# Istanbul to Mumbai on single ticket

Tags: luggage, short-connections, turkish-airlines, etihad, auh

I have a ticket from Istanbul to Mumbai with a layover in Abu Dabhi. The IST-AUH leg is on Turkish airlines and the AUH-BOM is on Etihad airlines. The entire ticket is on one single PNR but Turkish gave me its own PNR and Etihad gave me its own. Both PNRs list the entire journey. Since these two airlines are not in the same alliance, Will my bags go through all the way to Mumbai? The layover in AUH is 2 hr 20 min and if I will have to check in my bags again for Etihad, I doubt if this layover would be enough.

Comment: It's normal. If airlines are differents you need to check out again your baggage. Maybe is better if you change your second flight because maybe 2 hours are not so much for another check in again.

Comment: I would call the airlines and ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etihad states that they [interline baggage](https://www.etihad.com/en/before-you-fly/baggage-information/allowances/) with Turkish Airlines, among many others, so as long as you are on a single booking, your baggage will be transferred for you. You will not need to go through immigration or recheck your bags at AUH.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that you can expect your luggage to be checked in all the way if:

1) Same airline, same booking OR

2) Different airlines, same booking OR

3) Same airline, different bookings

To allay doubts, just call the airline(s).